# search a string for a email address with specific domain names

Tags: php, regex

How to get all emails, from text, that have these domain names

```
[@yahoo.com, @google.com, @bla.net]
```

in one regx

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@blabla\.com$ but i dont know how to do multiple domains

Comment: Why not just check that it ends with `@domain.com` ? How you have it now, any emails with a `.` or `-` or `_` and any other valid character that can be used in emails will fail your validation.

Comment: Your question is slightly ambiguous. Do you mean get *all* e-mail addresses from a string containging @ google.com, @ google.com, @ bla.net or do you want to just get e-mail addresses from those domains in a string?

Comment: yes, I want all the addresses extracted from the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\b[^ ]+@(yahoo\.com|google\.com|bla\.net)\b
```

This matches:

[image]

In php this becomes

```
preg_match_all('/\b[^@]*@(yahoo\.com|google\.com|bla\.net)\b/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```

Comment: This is way too greedy (will match from the start of any string with `@yahoo.com` in it, including newlines etc.) http://www.rubular.com/r/GzGDvOFERb

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can modify your current regex to accept those domains:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@(?:blabla\.com|google\.com|bla\.net)$
```

This uses a non-capturing group `(?:...)` with alternation `...|...` so that your regex will accept any of the domains you listed.

Answer (score 2):

\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@(yahoo|google|bla)+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b

I also recommending [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) if you want to build or test regular expressions.